# What is the difference between automate and automize?

Tags: word-choice, synonyms

We are a bunch of non-native English speakers at work who often discuss automating various tasks in the sense of writing software to replace otherwise manual processes.

I (with an electrical engineering background) have always been used to *automate* [v.] / *automation* [n.]. Some of my colleagues use the terms *automize* [v.] / *automization* [n.]. What is the difference between the two and is the latter even a real term?

I suspect that *automize* is a misunderstanding of *automatize*. I think of *automate*/*automatize* as synonyms in which case I by far prefer the former. I find *automatize* way klunkier to pronounce.

Answer (score 5):

"Automize" isn't in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/automize), and has one attestation from 1902 in the [OED](https://www.oed.com/dictionary/automize_v) (from the American Journal of Psychology, referring to automatism rather than automation). Most hits are for companies named "Automize", rather than for the word in its (hypothetical) general sense.  I would not recommend using it.

As for "automation" vs "automization", both are well-attested and synonymous.  Use whichever sounds better in context.

Comment: I expect those saying "automize" are thinking of a word in their own native language.

Comment: They may also have heard “atomize” or “atomizer”, creating a mist from a liquid (spraying on some perfume or killing some bugs).

Comment: Both automation and automization are valid words but automation seems more common in software: [IBM](https://www.ibm.com/topics/automation), [Atlassian](https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/guides/automation/overview); automization is likely to be confused with atomization.

Comment: An NGram comparing the past participles [***automized*** and ***automated***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=automized%2Cautomated&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) avoids the distraction of hits for companies named "Automize". And makes it blindingly obvious that the ***-ize*** derivative has next to no currency. Its use certainly shouldn't be encouraged with the kind of people who might seek advice on such matters.

Comment: @FF ... Yes, they need help with recognisation of when a word has virtually zero currency.